# When is a norm of a formal power series over a local field a polynomial?

Tags: power-series, p-adic-number-theory, galois-extensions, local-field

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ and $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension. Then also $L(T)/K(T)$ and $L((T))/K((T))$ are Galois extensions with Galois group isomorphic to ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ by having this group act on coefficients (make it act on $T$ trivially).

Let $N: L((T)) \to K((T))$ denote the norm map.  It restricts to norm maps $L(T) \to K(T)$, $L[[T]] \to K[[T]]$, $L[T] \to K[T]$, and $L \to K$.
I am interested in converses when the norm value is a rational function of polynomial: for $f(T) \in L((T))$, if $N(f(T)) \in K(T)$ then is $f(T) \in L(T)$? If $N(f(T)) \in K[T]$ then is $f(T) \in L[T]$? (One can ask similar questions with $L$ and $K$ replaced by their rings of integers $O_L$ and $O_K$.) If the answer to these two questions is no, does it become yes if we assume the Galois group is cyclic or is a $p$-group (or both)?

I have tried taking a generic power series and computing its norm in terms of its coefficients. The coefficients of the norm are sums of $d$-term products of Galois twists of the original coefficients, where $d = [L:K]$. So when the norm is a polynomial, coefficients with large enough index must vanish, which gives us equations for the original coefficients. However, it is not clear whether this implies what we want.

Comment: I have substantially rewritten your question because the norm map makes sense on the formal Laurent series field $L((T))$, not just on the more complicated subring ${\rm Frac}(O_L[[T]])$ that was in the original version of the question. I think the broader context is a clearer one in which to pose your type of converse questions. Let me know if you dislike the change.

Comment: Every element of $1+t K[t]$ is a $[L:K]$-th power in $K[[t]]$, so it is in $N_{L/K}(K[[t]])$, and it is often not in $N_{L/K}(L[t])$.

Comment: @reuns: this may be basic, but why are elements of $1+t K[t]$ $[L:K]$th powers in $K[[t]]$?

Comment: $(1+h)^{1/n}=\sum_{n\ge 0} {1/[L:K]\choose n} h^n$ is in $K[[t]]$ if $h\in t K[[t]]$

Comment: Thank you! I guess you meant $(1+h)^{1/n}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{1/n}{i} h^i$. This indeed appears to provide counterexamples over $L[[t]]/K[[t]]$. These, however, won’t be counterexamples in the original formulation of the question: if $L/K$ is a $p$-extension, then $n$ is a $p$-power, and the binomial coefficients in the sum have unbounded absolute values – hence these series won’t arise as fractions of power series in $O_L[[t]]$.